# Evaluate an expression within an environment inside a function

Tags: r

Consider:

```
guy <- new.env(FALSE)
guy$stuff <- mean
guy$lib <- library
guy$stole_this_data <- mtcars
ls(guy)
```

How can I evaluate an expression within an environment inside a function?

For instance I can do `with(guy, args(stuff))` to the below and return:

```
> with(guy, args(stuff))
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

But within a functon:

```
foo <- function(env, fun) {
    with(env, args(fun))
}

foo(guy, stuff)

## > foo(guy, stuff)
## Error in args(fun) : could not find function "stuff"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
> foo <- function(env, fun) eval(substitute(args(fun)), env)
> foo(guy, stuff)
function (x, ...) 
NULL
```

*ADDED.* Regarding the comment below here is an example where `zz` is not in `env` or its ancestors (but is in `foo2` and in `f`, the caller of `foo2`) and it *does* give a *not found* error as the comment wished:

```
> foo2 <- function(env, fun, zz = 1) eval(substitute(fun), env)
> f <- function() { zz <- 100; foo2(guy, zz+1) }
> f()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'zz' not found
```

Comment: I'll just point that the behavior here is slightly different from how `with` would act on an environment when called inside a function. If the expression you give to `substitute` contains a variable that is not defined in the the environment, but is defined in the scope of the function, that value will be substituted, instead of an error being raised.

Comment: but what if `zz` is defined in the global scope? It works in that case.

Comment: It should work in that case because the global environment is an ancestor of `guy`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to continue to use the `with` construct, this is an alternative:

```
foo <- function(env, fun) {
      fun <- substitute(fun)
      eval(bquote(with(env, {
        .(fun)
      })))
}
```